# Symmetric group of disjoint union from symmetric groups of the individual sets

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, terminology, symmetric-groups

Throughout, the index $i$ runs over $i=1,2$.

Let $A_i$ be disjoint sets with union $A$. Consider the symmetric groups $S^{(i)} = \mathrm{Symm}(A_i)$ and $S = \mathrm{Symm}(A)$. The $S^{(i)}$ embed as subgroups of $S$ in an obvious way. They have trivial intersection and commute with each other, and their product set is a proper subgroup of $G$. Is there some kind of standard binary operation, maybe call it , that takes two groups and forms a third, such that $S^{(1)}  S^{(2)} \simeq S$?

**Edit**: to clarify, there is a standard term for the relationship between $S$ and the elementwise product (further edit here) *of the embedded subgroups* $T = S^{(1)} S^{(2)}$, which is in this case also the direct product $S^{(1)} \times S^{(2)}$. Specifically, $T$ is the stabilizer of the partition $A = A_1 \sqcup A_2$, and is a <s>normal</s> subgroup of $S$. The quotient $S/T$ measures the extent to which permutations of $A$ can mix up $A_1$ and $A_2$.

Comment: Direct product?

Comment: No. Not every permutation on $A$ arises from permuting $A_1$ and $A_2$ individually.  What if some member of $A_1$ should map to a member of $A_2$?

Comment: There is no such standard binary operation that I know of.

Comment: The edit didn't clarify anything for me.  What is the elementwise product if they are not already subgroups of a common parent?  And why would that be the direct product?

Comment: @Randall further edit made, thanks.

Comment: You realize that full permutation groups have precious few normal subgroups, right? So any such putative $S$ will not in general be a full permutation group on $A$. Obviously you can take the normalizer of $S_1S_2$ in $S_A$, but that won't have the property you want it to have.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin thanks, that was sloppy on my part. Not sure why I thought it would be normal.